# Can WSPBuilder be used with Sandbox Solutions?

Tags: wspbuilder, sandbox-solution

Does anyone know if you can use WSPBuilder to create Sandbox Solutions for SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Most of the functionality of WSPBuilder is part of Visual Studio 2010 now.  Is there something in particular that you need WSPBuilder for?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be used to create Sandboxed solutions. BUT - you don't get the validations etc that Visual Studio OOB gives you.

Comment: Yea that makes sense.  According to the MS documentation, the two types of solutions are packaged in exactly the same way.  Where I get confused is the deployment target.  Since sandbox solutions are uploaded to the solutions gallery for the site collection and not the farm, wouldn't WSPBuilder specifically have to support this?